# How to calculate % difference of a column's different values

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

[image]There is a column - Current Product - which has two values according to the value of stocked column. That means when stocked is empty then it is called 'current product' and when it has some value then it is called 'Match'.   like this.....

```
==================================================================
Current Product       Stocked    AnnualSavings     Sodium
 Current product                                    450.00                    
  Match               yes          1234.00          432.00
```

Now there is a sodium text box in SSRS 2008 R2  report with a null. When a user enters 10
then we have to check match value of sodium is 10% less and equal to that of current product.

How can i do this...?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly the query below would work as an SSRS dataset. I think you want to select any rows from the table that have the Stocked field not null, and the Sodium within a certain range of "Current Product" The range is specified by the user as a parameter to the report.

It will be much easier to filter this in the query of the data set then in the report itself, since it depends on comparing values between records.

I think adding a few more rows to your example table would help if I missed this.

```
;
WITH
(
SELECT
   [Current Product] ,
   [Stocked] ,
   [OriginalProduct] ,
   [Sodium(Mg)]
FROM
   #TempConversion7
WHERE
   MemberPurchaseDataId IN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                              MemberPurchaseDataId
                             FROM
                              #TempConversion7
                             WHERE
                              SrNo > 1 )
                              ) AS ListCTE

SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN CurrentProd.[Sodium(Mg)]  >=
    ( MatchProd.[Sodium(Mg)] *(1.0 - ( @MatchValueParameter * 0.01)))
    AND CurrentProd.[Sodium(Mg)]  <=
    ( MatchProd.[Sodium(Mg)] *(1.0 + ( @MatchValueParameter * 0.01)))
    THEN
    1
    ELSE 0
    END
    AS WithinPercentRange
FROM
ListCTE AS CurrentProd
FULL OUTER JOIN
ListCTE AS MatchProd
ON CurrentProd.OriginalProduct = MatchProd.OriginalProduct
AND CurrentProd.[Current Product] = 'Current Product'
AND MatchProd.[Current Product] = 'Match'
```

Comment: It has given me the error like this      Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Not helpful how? Still the same error? If so, can you provide some sample data in your question that would let me recreate the problem?

Comment: I have attache another image  above for your understanding.<br/>here is my sql query for data retreival   select [Current Product],[Stocked],[OriginalProduct],[Sodium(Mg)]  from #TempConversion7
WHERE MemberPurchaseDataId IN (SELECT DISTINCT MemberPurchaseDataId FROM #TempConversion7 WHERE SrNo>1)
ORDER BY DNUSFS,ParentName,PIMClassDescription,MemberPurchaseDataId,SrNo ASC,TempAnnSaving ASC

Comment: Jamie,i think you r not actual getting my point.please review again the above code and [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898437/ssrs-parameter-logic-needed

Comment: please help,i am  not getting over this.i just want to show all the records of my table only sodium column should affected based on the formula i have already discussed.if the match sodium is 10% less of current product then both the records will show ,if not then not show.i think this will give  you a clear understanding.

Comment: Your requirements are very unclear. Is the screenshot the columns you want back? The  I've edited my answer to have a self-join, this might get you close. It is not clear what you have as input and what you want as output. I get the 10% range of records, but what columns? the query you provided refers to many different columns, and is hard to work with without sample data.